# HTTP client for company services

Tags: ruby, http

For quite a while now I've been writing a bit of Ruby code, but so far I still don't think it was good idiomatic Ruby. But there's been a new requirement and I tried my best writing it better, more cleanly compared to my previous code. One of the things I did is read another code base that I though was well written (calabash-ios).

I would like to hear your opinions and suggestions for improvements.

```
module Company
  module MobileServices
    class Client
      include DigestHelper

      attr_reader :client_name, :client_digest_key

      # headers that will be part of every request type 
      REQUEST_INIT_HEADER = {
          'User-Agent' => 'Calabash/MobileServicesClient',
          'Accept' => 'application/json'        
      }

      # when creating a new instance, make sure the client name and digest key 
      # are correct as a digest key is linked to a specific client
      def initialize(client_name = 'client_x', client_digest_key = 'some_random_key')
        @client_name = client_name       
        @client_digest_key = client_digest_key 
      end

      # execute request base on path; optionally add the following parameters
      # - user_id: a registered email address for the target environment (host)
      # - password: the password linked to the email address
      # - host: default is some.host.nl, change as needed
      # - http_method: GET (default), PUT, POST or DELETE are supported
      # - body: the body of the request, only JSON content is supported
      #
      # PLEASE NOTE: we can't get URL's through proxy working, digest 
      # calculation seems to fail
      def execute_request(path, options={})
        default_options = {:host => 'some.host.nl',
                           :user_id => 'account@example.com',
                           :password => 'pa55w0rd',
                           :http_method => 'GET',
                           :body => ''}

        options = default_options.merge(options)

        digest = calc_digest(path, options[:user_id], @client_digest_key, options[:body])
        uri = URI.parse("https://" + options[:host] + path + "?digest=#{digest}")

        # create a request and add the default headers like authorization and host        
        http_request = new_http_request(uri, options[:http_method], options[:body])
        add_default_headers(http_request, options[:host], options[:user_id], options[:password])

        # create a new http client that we'll use to execute the request
        http_client = new_http_client(uri, digest)

        # execute request & print results
        puts "\n#{uri}\n\n"
        puts "#{http_request.method} #{http_request.path}"
        http_request.each_header {|key,value| puts "#{key} = #{value}" }
        puts "\n"
        http_response = http_client.request(http_request)
        puts "#{http_response.code} #{http_response.message}\n"
        puts "#{http_response.body}" unless http_response.body.nil?
        puts "\n--------------------------------------------------------------\n"
      end

  private #---------------------------------------------------------------------

      # create a new http client and in case of https we mark it as SSL, but we
      # wont verify the certificates
      def new_http_client(uri, digest)
        http_client = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

        if uri.scheme == 'https'
          http_client.use_ssl = true
          http_client.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
        end

        http_client
      end

      # create a new http request with an optional body; when a body exists, we 
      # assume it's JSON content and add the appropriate header
      def new_http_request(uri, http_method, body = '')
        http_request = nil

        # depending on the http method type, create the appropriate request type
        case http_method
        when 'GET'
          http_request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, REQUEST_INIT_HEADER)
        when 'PUT'
          http_request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri.request_uri, REQUEST_INIT_HEADER)
        when 'POST'
          http_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, REQUEST_INIT_HEADER)
        when 'DELETE'
          http_request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.request_uri, REQUEST_INIT_HEADER)
        else 
          raise "invalid or unsupported HTTP method: #{http_method}"
        end

        # we'll assume body content is always JSON, so if we have a body we'll
        # add the content type header
        unless body == ''
          http_request.add_field("Content-Type", "application/json") 
          http_request.body = body
        end

        http_request
      end

      # adds the following headers to a request:
      # - host: the server we're connecting with
      # - client-name: the client that is linked to our digest
      # - authorization: a hashed value based on user id and password
      def add_default_headers(http_request, host, user_id, password)
        unless http_request.nil?
          http_request.basic_auth(user_id, password)
          http_request.add_field("Client-Name", @client_name)
          http_request.add_field("Host", host)           
        end

        http_request
      end

    end
  end
end
```

---

```
module Company
  module MobileServices
    module DigestHelper

      def calc_digest(path, user_id, digest_key, body='')
        body = body.bytes[0..1000].pack('c*')
        text = path + body + user_id + digest_key
        digest = Digest::SHA1.digest(text)
        hex_digest = digest.unpack('H*').first.downcase

        hex_digest
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In (subjective) order or relevance:

---

You shouldn't really raise a RuntimeError (default):

```
raise "invalid or unsupported HTTP method: #{http_method}"
```

Instead, define your own exception class and raise it:

```
HttpMethodError = Class.new(StandardError)
...
raise HttpMethodError, "invalid method #{method}"
```

RuntimeError is pretty generic, and if something else throws it, your `rescue` statements could not tell the difference, making it hard to handle such exception.

---

Your methods are somewhat long thus unreadable. Find atomic tasks and extract them, i.e.

```
  def request_for_method http_method
    case http_method
    when 'GET'
      Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, REQUEST_INIT_HEADER)
    when 'PUT'
      Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri.request_uri, REQUEST_INIT_HEADER)
    when 'POST'
      http_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, REQUEST_INIT_HEADER)
    when 'DELETE'
      Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.request_uri, REQUEST_INIT_HEADER)
    else 
      raise "invalid or unsupported HTTP method: #{http_method}"
    end
  end
```

You could also split `execute_request` in at least two parts (logic in first, `puts`es in second.

---

Newer version's of Ruby (2.0 up I think) would allow you to turn this:

```
  def execute_request(path, options={})
    default_options = {:host => 'some.host.nl',
                       :user_id => 'account@email.com',
                       :password => 'pa55w0rd',
                       :http_method => 'GET',
                       :body => ''}
```

into this:

```
def execute_requests(path, host: 'some.host.nl', user_id: 'account@email.com' ...)
```

---

There's no need to check for nil explicitly:

```
unless http_request.nil?
# equals
if http_request
```

Likewise:

```
unless body == ''
# equals
unless body.empty?
```

Some people would argue that second option is more readable.

---

This is more like a hint, or an opinion than an issue: if you have such deeply nested code you can do things like:

```
class Company::MobileServices::Client
  include DigestHelper
  # ...
end
```

While I'd say it makes your code more readable (provided you only have single class in a file), in Ruby we most often only use two spaces to indent, so it's not really a problem.

---

Even if you don't extract this `case` in it's method (or if you do), don't assign to variable in each `when`. Ruby way to do this is to leverage the fact that `case` is an expression returning a value (like everything else is):

```
    http_request =
      case http_method
      when 'GET'
        Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, REQUEST_INIT_HEADER)
      when 'PUT'
        Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri.request_uri, REQUEST_INIT_HEADER)
      when 'POST'
      # ...
      end
```

Comment: Thanks Bosunho, you gave me some excellent feedback. Much appreciated!